# How can I delete multiple occurrences in a linked list?

Tags: java

I believe I have the code on how to remove an item in a linked list but I'm not sure how I can make it so that all occurrences of a value would be removed. Where would I need to make some changes that would have it check through all the values in the list?

I've tried to make an alternate or a dummy that pointed to the head but I wasn't sure where I was going with that.

```
public class LinkList {

private Link first;            // ref to first link on list

// -------------------------------------------------------------
public LinkList() // constructor
{
    first = null;               // no links on list yet
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void insertFirst(int id, double dd) {                           
    Link newLink = new Link(id, dd);
    newLink.next = first;       // it points to old first link
    first = newLink;            // now first points to this
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public Link find(int key) // find link with given key
{                           // (assumes non-empty list)
    Link current = first;              // start at 'first'
    while (current.iData != key) // while no match,
    {
        if (current.next == null) // if end of list,
        {
            return null;                 // didn't find it
        } else // not end of list,
        {
            current = current.next;      // go to next link
        }
    }
    return current;                    // found it
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------
public void displayList() // display the list
{
    System.out.print("List (first-->last): ");
    Link current = first;       // start at beginning of list
    while (current != null) // until end of list,
    {
        current.displayLink();   // print data
        current = current.next;  // move to next link
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public Link removeAll(int n) // delete link with given key
{                           // (assumes non-empty list)
    Link current = first;              // search for link
    Link previous = first;

    while (current.iData != n) {
        if (current.next == null) {
            return null;                 // didn't find it
        } else {
            previous = current;          // go to next link
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    if (current == first) // if first link,
    {
        first = first.next;             //    change first
    } else // otherwise,
    {
        previous.next = current.next;   //    bypass it
    }
    return current;
  }
}
```

I expect to have all the values deleted for a given key but it I'm only able to delete one instance of a given value.

Comment: Put everything in Set and then create a list from it again.

Comment: Assuming the linked-list is terminated by `null`, you can make the loop run `while(current != null)` and for each link check if `current.iData == n`. If true, remove the link and continue processing.

Comment: What is the purpose of returning a Link?  Should that return the first one deleted? ...the last one deleted?  You won't know how many were deleted.

Comment: If I try that suggestion @Jeppe  all my values reappear instead of the single value that was only deleted before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes all occurrences of `Link` with `id == n`. It should be the same if you want to remove by `Link.iData`.

```
public Link removeAll(int n)
{
    Link head = first;
    Link previous = null;
    Link current = first;

    while (current != null) {
        if (current.id == n) {
            if (previous == null) {
                head = current.next;
            } else {
                previous.next = current.next;
            }
        } else {
            previous = current; // if we removed current, let previous remain the same
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    first = head;
    return head;
}
```

Running the code like this:

```
LinkList l = new LinkList();
l.insertFirst(0, 0.1);
l.insertFirst(3, 3.1);
l.insertFirst(1, 1.1);
l.insertFirst(3, 3.1);
l.insertFirst(2, 2.1);
l.displayList();
l.removeAll(3);
l.displayList();
```

Outputs:

```
List (first-->last): 
2 : 2.1
3 : 3.1
1 : 1.1
3 : 3.1
0 : 0.1

List (first-->last): 
2 : 2.1
1 : 1.1
0 : 0.1
```

Comment: At the end current will be null, and so you are returning null, isnt it?

Comment: This will not correctly update the `first` reference if the very first Link should be deleted...

Answer (score 0):

I have this class called `ListNode`, similar to yours.

```
public class ListNode {

    public ListNode next;
    public int val;

    public ListNode removeAll(int n) {
        ListNode newHead = null;
        ListNode node = this;

        //for keeping track of the node previous to the current node
        ListNode prev = null;
        //loop through the entire linked list
        while (node != null) {

            //when you encounter the val == n, delete the node
            if (node.val == n) {

                if (prev != null){
                    //this makes the previous node to point the node to the next of the current node
                    //if 2 -> 1 -> 3 and we have to remove node with key 1 and current node val == 1
                    // the following code will do this
                    // 2 -> 3
                    prev.next = node.next;
                }

                ListNode next = node.next;
                //taking the same example
                //this code will break the link : 1->3
                node.next = null;
                node = next;
            } else {
                if (newHead == null) {
                    newHead = node;
                }
                prev = node;
                node = node.next;
            }
        }
        return newHead;
    }
}
```

You, basically, have to traverse through whole linked list, keeping track of the previous node for the current node and when you find a node with value/key/data equal to n, you make the previous node point to the next node of the current node and break the link of the current node to the next node.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first start without deleting anything.  To delete all occurrences, you first need to be able to iterate over the entire list (so you can look for multiple matches).  Iterating over the whole list would simply be:

```
public void removeAll(int n) // delete link with given key
{
    Link current = first;
    Link previous = first;

    while (current != null)
    {
        // simply move to the next Link
        previous = current; // store the current node as the previous for the next iteration
        current = current.next; // move to the next link
    }
}
```

Next, let's add in a check to see if the current Link is one that should be deleted:

```
public void removeAll(int n) // delete link with given key
{
    Link current = first;
    Link previous = first;

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.iData == n)
        {   
            // To do...delete the current Link
        }
        else
        {
            // simply move to the next Link
            previous = current; // store the current node as the previous for the next iteration
            current = current.next; // move to the next link
        }       
    }
}
```

Once we've found a match, there are two possibilities.  Either the Link is the first Link, or it is somewhere further down in the list:

- If the link is the first one, then we move current to the next Link, and make both first and previous point to the new current Link.
- If we are not the first Link, then we move current to the next Link, and update the previous.next field to point to the new current Link (thus skipping over the Link to delete).

Here's the updated code:

```
public void removeAll(int n) // delete link with given key
{
    Link current = first;
    Link previous = first;

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.iData == n)
        {   
            if (current == first)
            {       
                current = current.next;
                first = current;
                previous = current;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current.next;
                previous.next = current;            
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // simply move to the next Link
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple recursive implementation (this implementation leaves initial list intact, and creates new without specified element):

```
public class Answer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList(1, new LinkedList(2, new LinkedList(1, new LinkedList(2, new LinkedList(3, null)))));
    System.out.println(list);
    LinkedList withoutOne = list.removeAll(1);
    System.out.println(withoutOne);
    LinkedList withoutTwo = list.removeAll(2);
    System.out.println(withoutTwo);
    LinkedList withoutThree = list.removeAll(3);
    System.out.println(withoutThree);
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  private int value;
  private LinkedList next;

  public LinkedList(int value, LinkedList next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
  }

  public LinkedList removeAll(int value) {
    if (this.next == null) {
      return (this.value == value) ? null : new LinkedList(this.value, null);
    } else if (this.value == value) {
      return this.next.removeAll(value);
    } else {
      return new LinkedList(this.value, this.next.removeAll(value));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    String res = "LinkedList:";
    for (LinkedList link = this; link != null; link = link.next) {
      res += " " + link.value;
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're creating **NEW** LinkedList instances for existing nodes that aren't being deleted.  This would break any existing references to those Links outside of your routine...I suppose it just depends how you're using the lists; just seems weird to me.

Comment: @Idle_Mind It depends on what you prefer: mutable or immutable objects.